# Gridjs-react: Sort by column having a React Component

Tags: reactjs, gridjs

I'm using gridjs-react to create a custom grid as follows:

```
import { Grid, _ } from 'gridjs-react';

const tableData = [
  ['John', 12345, _(<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="1" disabled checked />)],
  ['Mike', 67891, _(<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="2" disabled />)],
]

export default function myCustomGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid
      sort
      columns={['Name', 'Phone', 'Checkbox']}
      data={tableData}
      pagination={{
        enabled: true,
        limit: 5,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

The output is a table that contains 2 rows, It can be sorted by "Name" and "Phone". However It cannot be sorted by the "Checkbox" column that has <input> or any other React Component.

I ultimately want to be able to sort the table depending on whether the checkbox is checked or disabled or by its value if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
import { Grid, _ } from 'gridjs-react';

const tableData = [
  ['John', 12345, true],
  ['Mike', 67891, false],
]

export default function myCustomGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid
      sort
      columns={[
        'Name', 
        'Phone', 
        {
          name: 'Enabled', 
          formatter: (isEnabled) => _(renderEnabled(isEnabled)) 
        }
      ]}
      data={tableData}
      pagination={{
        enabled: true,
        limit: 5,
      }}
    />
  );
}

const renderEnabled = (isEnabled) => {
  switch (isEnabled) {
    case true:
      return <input type="checkbox" disabled checked />;
    case false:
      return <input type="checkbox" disabled />;
    default:
      return <b>Dunno</b>;
  }
};
```